Reveal.js does not load in a dynamic SPA view loader
I am trying to dynamic load Reveal.js inside a basic SPA router in vanilla JS, but I simply can't get Reveal.js running. I get the background, so it is recognized and the files are loaded. It just doesn't give me the slides correctly. I simply can't find the solution neither with Google, LLM's or anything like these. Can anybody help me before I get completely insane :-)
index.html
main.js
|- views
|  |- index.html
|  |- index.js

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>

main.js
const route = (event) => {
  event = event || window.event;
  event.preventDefault();
  window.history.pushState({}, '', event.target.href);
  handleLocation();
};

const routes = {
  '/': { title: 'Home', path: '/views/index.html', script: '/views/index.js' },
  '404': { title: '404', path: '/views/404.html' },
};

const handleLocation = async () => {
  const path = window.location.pathname;
  const route = routes[path]?.path || routes['404'].path;
  const html = await fetch(route).then((data) => data.text());
  document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = html;

  // Load scripts
  if (routes[path]?.script) {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'module';
    script.src = routes[path].script;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
};

window.onpopstate = handleLocation;
window.route = route;

handleLocation();

views/index.html
<div class="reveal">
  <div class="slides">
    <section>
      <h1>Ladida</h1>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

views/index.js
import 'reveal.js/dist/reset.css';
import 'reveal.js/dist/reveal.css';
import 'reveal.js/dist/theme/black.css';

import Reveal from 'reveal.js';
import Highlight from 'reveal.js/plugin/highlight/highlight.esm.js';

(async () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    Reveal.initialize({
      plugins: [Highlight],
      slideNumber: 'c/t',
      showSlideNumber: 'all',
    });
  });
})();


I forogt to mention that I am running everything with vite as a vanilla project and the dependencies are installed.
